# google sheets regextract nth occurence on new line

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Example Data (all in one google sheet cell)

```
Test# 123
Bob# abc
how are you doing
John# test
... # ...
```

My goal is to return everything after the third # so in this example " test" I have fiddled with a lot of examples online but they seem to be incompatible with the google sheets version of regextract for some reason.

I can use (\n.*){4} to return the fourth line but that is no good because as you can see from the example data I do not know how many lines of data will be between a # and also that is not extracting from the # let alone the third #.

Goal: extract the third # to the end of the line including or excluding the # will do.

Here is an idea I have but surely the format is all butchered ((\n)(?=#.*)){3} I would expect this regex to grab the third # IF it was the beginning of the line but I can't even get that working let alone if it were to occur in the middle of the line was as was my example.

Comment: Try `=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "^(?:[^#]*#){3}(.+)")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Works perfectly! Thank you! Would it be easy to modify this to grab the text between the third # and the fourth # or should I ask that as another question?

Comment: I added the details to the answer.

Comment: `.+` is a "greedy dot" pattern, it matches all the 1 or more chars other than line break chars at once (i.e. all the text to the end of the line).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "^(?:[^#]*#){3}(.+)")
```

To get all text from the 3rd till the 4th `#` char:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "^(?:[^#]*#){3}([^#]+)")
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[^#]*#){3}` - three occurrences of 0+ chars other than `#` and then `#` (the `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group, you need it to group a sequence of patterns without the need to return the text this group pattern matches)
- `(.+)` - Capturing group 1 (`REGEXEXTRACT` returns the text captured into the group only if the group is specified): any 1+ chars other than line break chars
- `([^#]+)` - this captures into Group 1 any one or more chars other than `#`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

also works:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(INDEX(SPLIT(A1, "#"),,4), " (.+)")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This is a good idea as well, I know it is explained in the other answer but can you explain again what (.+) exactly does?

Comment: sure, dot represents 1 character and + means "all characters after 1st character" eg. "continue with whatever there is"